# Can't apply Content Type to content. Does't appear in drop down

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type

I have a Content Type called Ice Inspection Videos in an Asset Library.  When I upload a video, the content type does not appear so I can't apply it.  Any thoughts?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Exactly Where the content type is not appearing?

Comment: In the second image.  When I view the properties of the video, and click in the content type field, the content type is not in the dropdown.

Comment: What is the parent content type of "Ice Inspection videos"?

Comment: This depends on what kind of content type you created and the parent. I just added a document content type and was able to see it in the drop down

Comment: The parent type of Ice Inspection Videos is Ice Inspection Videos???  In Site Setting -> Content Types, Its parent is Video, but when I click on the Content Type in Library Settings it says Ice Inspection Videos is the parent.  Please see third screen shot just added.

Comment: One question, could you tell the whole hierarchy of the ice inspection videos content type? I mean parent, parent of parent and so on until reaching Item content type.

Comment: Ice inspection Videos content type is a child of Ice Inspection Videos content type when you add it to a library. That allows to make changes to it in the library without modifying the master.

Comment: @jaloplo can you please tell me how to provide the whole hierarchy of Ice Inspection Content type?

Comment: @Martin Muldoon you can get it clicking on each parent of each content type. For example, you clicked on Ice Inspection Videos content type of the list and you got it Ice Inspection Videos content type as it's parent, you can click again on this content type and you will get it's parent, and so on. Then provide the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create the “Ice Inspection Videos” content type by yourself? Did the issue only occur on the video file?

From your screenshot, the video file which you upload to the asset library is identified as the photo.

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Upload other videos into the asset library and check if the same issue will occur.
2. And remove and re-add the “Ice Inspection Videos” content type and set the “Ice 
   Inspection Videos” content type as default content type.